# how to remove multiple rows that match more than 1 pattern in R?

Tags: r, grepl

Hello I'm trying to remove rows that match more than 1 pattern using `grepl` this  is what I tried:

```
custom_BGCs[!grepl(c("Chloroflexota","Desulfobacterota_D",
                     "Gemmatimonadota"),custom_BGCs$Phylum),]
```

on this fashion only "Chloroflexota" rows are removed with a warning message that only rows with the first specified pattern are removed.

> Warning message: In grepl(c("Chloroflexota", "Desulfobacterota_D",
> "Gemmatimonadota",  :   the argument 'pattern' has a length >
> 1 and only he first element will be used

How can I remove the other ones?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep/grepl` is not vectorized for pattern.  Use `|` to combine them into a single string

```
custom_BGCs[!grepl(paste(c("Chloroflexota","Desulfobacterota_D",
                     "Gemmatimonadota"), collapse = "|"),custom_BGCs$Phylum),]
```